# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() & TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterable

I have a dataset imported as DataFrame "new_data_words". There is a column "page_name" containing messy webpage names, like "`%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81:%D8%A2%D9%84%D9...`", "`%D9%85%D9%84%D9%81:IT-Airforce-OR2.png`" or simply "`1950`". I want to create a new column 'word_count' to have the count of words in the page name (words are delimited by '_')

Here are my codes:

To split to words:

```
b = list(new_data_words['page_name'].str.split('_'))
new_data_words['words'] = b
```

I checked the type of b is **list** type and len(b) is **6035980**.
One sample value:

```
In [1]: new_data_words.loc[0,'words']
Out[2]: ['%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81:%D8%A2%D9%84%D9%87%D8%A9',
         '%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF',
         '%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86']
```

I created another column "word_count" to count the elements of the list in each row of column "words". (Have to use loop to touch the elements of list in each row)

But I had errors:

```
x = []
i = []
c = 0
for i in b:    # i is list type, with elements are string, I checked
    c=c+1
    x.append(len(i))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c0cf0cfbc458> in <module>()
      6         #y = str(y)
      7     c=c+1
----> 8     x.append(len(i))

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I don't know why it is float type.....

However if I only add a print, it worked

```
x = []
i = []
c = 0
for i in b:
    c=c+1
    print len(i)
    x.append(len(i))

3
2
3
2
3
1
8
...
```

But c = len(x) = 68516, much smaller than 6 millions.

I tried to force the elements to be string again, another error happened:

```
x = []
for i in b:
    for y in i:
        y = str(y)
    x.append(len(i))


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-c86f5f48b80c> in <module>()
      1 x = []
      2 for i in b:
----> 3     for y in i:
      4         y = str(y)
      5     x.append(len(i))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I think i is list type and is iterable...

Again, if I did not append, but only print, it worked:

```
x = []
for i in b:
    for y in i:
        y = str(y)
    print (len(i))
```

---

Another example:
This works:

```
a = []
for i in range(10000):
    a.append(len(new_data_words.loc[i,"words"]))
```

Changed to a dynamic range, it does not work:

```
a = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    a.append(len(new_data_words.loc[i,"words"]))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f9d0af3c448f> in <module>()
      1 a = []
      2 for i in range(len(b)):
----> 3     a.append(len(new_data_words.loc[i,"words"]))

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

This does not work either......

```
a = []
for i in range(6035980):
    a.append(len(new_data_words.loc[i,"words"]))
```

Seems like there are some abnormal in the list. But I don't know what that is or how to find it.

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong. The errors you're seeing make it 100% clear that `b` is an iterable containing at least one `float` (whether the other elements are `str` or not I won't speculate).

Try doing:

```
for i in b:
    print(type(i), i)
```

and you'll see there is at least one `float`. Or this to only print the non-iterable components of `b`:

```
import collections

for i in b:
    if not isinstance(i, collections.Iterable):
        print(type(i), i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was due to null values in 'Page_value' column. Even though I cast all the element to string, null will still be float.