# Intermittent 'TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()' when creating dataframe from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

[What I thought was my solution isn't quite my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110422/unpacking-a-pandas-dataframe-column-that-contains-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-ne).

The "solution" code:

```
# Get "raw" data
orig_df = pd.DataFrame(list(jobs["jobs_by_id"]))

# Creates df but removes the NaN elements
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(orig_df[0]).dropna())   

# Get the orig_df indexes of non-NaN rows to apply to the new df
new_ndx = new_df.index[orig_df[0].notna()]

# Reset index and give new indexes that will line up
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df = new_df.set_index(new_ndx)

# Now apply the new_df to the orig_df
orig_df= pd.concat([orig_df, new_df ], axis=1)
```

Now I am running into an intermittent `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`.  This error is thrown on the first line in the code sample above.  Sometimes the code runs as expected, sometimes it throws the `TypeError`.

I [found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700363/typeerror-object-of-type-float-has-no-len-typeerror-float-object-is-no) and did as the answer suggested, print out each element in the column/series and see what type it is.  I know some rows/elements will be empty and will contain `NaN.`
Both sets of job steps have `NaN` elements in the series, yet some process just fine, while others error out.  Both success and error batches have a combination of a lists of dictionaries **and** `NaN`.  There are no malformed dictionaries in either data set, and all data types are as expected.

This job batch executes just fine:

```
Processing  JOB_123456
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
SUCCESS
```

Yet this one...

```
Processing  JOB_99999
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'float'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs.py", line 743, in <module>
    dump_events('2021-04-13')
  File "jobs.py", line 198, in job_events
    orig_df = pd.DataFrame(list(jobs["jobs_by_id"]))
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 450, in __init__
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 464, in to_arrays
    return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 496, in _list_to_arrays
    content = list(lib.to_object_array(data).T)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2275, in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Why is python not happy in only some instances?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to debug your code -

Add one more line just before line 198 of your code to check the datatype of 'jobs['jobs_by_id]'

```
print(type(jobs["jobs_by_id"])) # line to add
orig_df = pd.DataFrame(list(jobs["jobs_by_id"]))
```

In the 1st run where the script ran successfully you'll probably get the datatype as 'list'. But, with the 2nd run, the datatype maybe 'float' for some instances that's why you're getting this error.

You need to probably add some error handling in your code to fix the issue.

Comment: Would also suggest a try and except bit to fix the entries that are float. However, I would say you generally want all data types in the column to be the same so the same code can run for all of it. If some are going to be lists and some floats just stick the floats in the list with only one entity.

Comment: The `float` representation is **not** an actual float value i.e 5.0, but is a `Nan`.  I don't know why python represents `NaN` as a `float` but here we are.  The `NaN` values are legitimate as not every element in the series will have a list of dictionaries, it could be empty.